# square of a float number in C

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I have written a code in C which works fine for int but when I try to do this with float it is showing error what can i do to make it correct.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a,y;
    float square();
    scanf("%f", &a);
    y = square( a );
    printf("%f %f ",a ,y);
}

float square(float b)
{
    float z;
    z = b*b;
    printf("%f %f",z ,b);
    return(z);
}
```

error:

```
return.c:12: error: conflicting types for 'square'
return.c:13: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can't match an empty parameter name list declaration
return.c:6: note: previous declaration of 'square' was here
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the declaration of `square()` out of the function and make sure the prototype matches:

```
float square(float b);  //  Make sure this matches the definition.

int main()
{
    float a,y;
    scanf("%f", &a);
    y = square( a );
    printf("%f %f ",a ,y);
}

float square(float b)
{
    float z;
    z = b*b;
    printf("%f %f",z ,b);
    return(z);
}
```

As for why it "worked" for `int`, you'll have to show us the exact code you used for that case.

Comment: C does something special for when you call functions that haven't been declared yet. It assumes that the arguments and return type is `int` or something, I can't remember exactly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. But I'm not sure on the exact behavior since I never use that functionality... Same applies to functions inside functions - it's an area I avoid.

Comment: Thanks both of both answers worked , I think C takes "int" if we have not declared type . Is that true what i am thinking of .

Comment: Yes, C does take a default int when no type is specified. However, this is depreciated and it's recommended to always specify the type. So my guess is that the default `int` allowed your initial case to work.

Answer (score 4):

You're just missing the argument in the prototype you gave. You had

```
float square();
```

When it should be

```
float square(float);
```

You don't need to move it outside the function, but you do need to make sure the prototype has the same signature (return type, name, and parameter count/types) as the function that you define later.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could leave the declaration inside the function. +1

Comment: @Mysticial that's where the annoying thing comes from where you cannot value-initialise a variable (or is it default initialise?) whose constructor takes no arguments: `MyClass m;` works but `MyClass m();` doesn't because it's a function prototype. (Same for builtin types too.)